# Sprite getting cropped in play window

Tags: unity, 2d, sprites

Video of behaviour:  https://youtu.be/yC5m6k3jf2o

The worm sprite in my *Scene Editor* is rendered correctly.

[image: Scene Editor]

When it's in the play window it's getting cropped on the bottom an right though/

[image: Play Window]

I've tried completely deleting the worm and re-adding it and the problem is still there.

The *Import Settings* are:

- Texture Type:  Sprite (2D and UI)
- Texture Share:  2D
- Sprite Mode:  Multiple
- Pixels Per Unit:  1
- Mesh Type:  Tight
- Extrude Edges:  1
- Generate Physics:  true
- Wrap Mode: Clamp
- Filter Mode:  Point (no filter)

**NB**:  Just discovered that if I drag directly onto the *Scene Editor* then it renders correctly, but if dragged onto the Hierarchy_

Comment: Not sure about unity, nor this at all, but could it be that the bird is drawn before the worm? What if you tried to draw the worm after the bird? (Presumably, the transparency of the bird image "covers" that part of the worm.)

Comment: @AlexandreVaillancourt I've moved the bird around and got rid of it, and added in different orders and shifted them in the hierarchy without and change.  I've also reproduced it with a different sprite.